# How to create a custom theme options page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a custom option theme page for my wordpress theme and i found this tutorial
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/create-a-settings-page-for-your-wordpress-theme/, but the problem is that it doesn't work, and i am afraid that is too outdated. I am using wordpress 3.7.1. The function that i added and tried to create the wordpress setting theme page is

```
function setup_theme_admin_menus() {  
    add_submenu_page('themes.php',   
        'Front Page Elements', 'Front Page', 'manage_options',   
        'front-page-elements', 'theme_front_page_settings');   
}  
function theme_front_page_settings() {  
    echo "Hello, world!";  
}
```

And i placed in my theme functions.php but nothing happened.

Comment: you dont get confused with big articles, check here - http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/10/creating-custom-options-page-wordpress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code :
add_action("admin_menu", "setup_theme_admin_menus");

Comment: Did not noticed it :).

Comment: this works if your the administrator, but what if you want another user level to also be able to see this page? say the editor level for example?